# What is the point of creating a typedef of an anonymous structure?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am relatively new to C and I came across a typedef for a structure with no name.

What is the point of it?

```
#define POLY(name,deg)    \
    term name[deg] = {0};

typedef struct {
  int coeff;
  int exp;
} term;
```

Comment: The typedef alias has a name; what it is missing is a *tag*.

Comment: What do you mean by tag?

Comment: `term` is the name of this type.

Comment: @BrianTBrennglass "tag" is the technical wording for the structure name. When you declare a structure like `struct A { ..}` then `A` is the "tag". For example, anonymous structure has no tag.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`term` alone can be used to represent the type then. In language C, with `struct term { ... };`, you will have to use `struct term` to refer to the type.

This is different from C++, where a definition like `struct term { ... };` implicitly introduces both `struct term` and `term` alone as valid references.

Comment: So it's shorthand for struct term?

Comment: It's shorthand for your anonymous struct

Comment: most of the structs i see have tags with an underscore prepended, so it would look like "typedef struct _term { int cooeff; int exp;} term;"

Comment: @BrianTBrennglass `term` is a type *alias*. It aliases the type immediately following the `typedef` keyword (that's how all type aliases work in C). In this case, that is an anonymous (untagged) compound type. As an anonymous type, you cannot `struct name something;` because there is no such name. Because of the alias, however, you can `term something;` and the meaning is clear.

Comment: yes and no; yes: any `typedef` introduces an alias and is then a "shorthand", if you like; no: as you introduce an anonymous struct, which has no "name", you would have no chance to refer to the struct otherwise, such that there is nothing for which it could be a shorthand; it's the only possibility then.

Comment: @Bwebb FIY, prepending a type (or identifier or a macro name) with underscore is undefined behavior according to C standard. Names with leading underscore are reserved for implementation. So please, don't do it.

Comment: I saw this comment in another thread.  fyi, page 166 of C99 draft, All identiﬁers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use. And All identiﬁers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identiﬁers with ﬁle scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ive been looking into this, and why i do it and why I've seen it in professional code.  It seems like its a MISRA(ble) thing:

Rule 5.6 (advisory): No identifier in one name space should have the same spelling as an identifier in another name space, with the exception of structure member and union member names. [MISRA C 2004]

Comment: @Bwebb I am working in a very professional environment and seeing it all over the place  :) But we have recently employed the SEI CERT standard and now having much troubles with this stuff. Here is the page helping interpret this rather vague standard wording: http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html

Comment: @EugeneSh Can you help me understand what you mean by "Names with leading underscore are reserved for implementation"?  Does this mean i shouldnt write libraries with _structname?  Does this mean if im writing embedded code that isnt a library I dont have to worry?  Thanks in advance. *EDIT* looking to SEI CERT

Comment: Bwebb  "Does this mean if im writing embedded code that isnt a library I dont have to worry?".  Yes, remain worried.  As @EugeneSh. said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082560/what-is-the-point-of-creating-a-typedef-of-an-anonymous-structure#comment94998828_54082582_), "don't do it".  "And All identiﬁers..."" is from the C spec.